# ClassNotFound Error when running Java .class file in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, compiler-errors, ubuntu-10.04

I compile my file with `javac myfile.java`
But when I run myfile.class file with command : `java myfile` I get an ClassNotFound error. My Java version is openjdk-6

Comment: Show us the full stack trace and your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command as this (in the same directory where you compiled):

`java -cp . myfile`

Assuming of course that the file contains a class called `myfile`, which btw, doesn't follow standard Java naming practices (should begin with a capital letter).

Read up on [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) more about setting your runtime classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your classpath is wrong. Try java -cp . myfile

Also, java tools tend to like javas normal conventions, so your class should be MyClass, and the file should then be MyClass.java